# Reverse diffusion of a gas

Tags: probability-theory

I have a question about the Ehrenfest model of gas diffusion.

Suppose I have two urns, each one with $N = 1,000,000$ balls in it. To start with, the first urn has only black balls, and the second only white ones. Every time the clock ticks, the urns exchange two balls: one chosen at random from the first urn goes to the second, and one similarly in the reverse direction.

Over time, the numbers of balls of each kind have a tendency to even out, so that once equilibrium is reached, the system typically spends most of its time hovering around $500,000$ black balls in each urn. However, with probability $1$, after a usually very long finite time, at some point the first urn will be down to, say, 45% black balls, a kind of "reverse diffusion" which in physical practice doesn't happen, due to the large number of gas molecules.

Nonetheless, let $T$ be the time it takes for the first urn to have $450,000$ black balls for the first time.

I would like to know if there is a way to find bounds for the expected value of $T$, the median of $T$, or any other parameters of its distribution. I suppose I'm most interested in the expected value.

I would appreciate a reference for this kind of problem if possible. The problem is reminiscent of random walks, but is different because the probability of a step left, a step right, or staying put depends on the present state of the system in such a way that drifting away from the $500,000$ mark becomes less likely.

Thanks.

Comment: You might be interested in reading this.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#One-dimensional_random_walk

Comment: @PeterFranek Thanks. In my situation, on any given step, it's more likely that you'll move back in the direction of the equilibrium point than the other way, and I think this changes the problem significantly.

Comment: Right, thanks for the comment.

Comment: This [article](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1103052190) computes the distribution of recurrence times of the Ehrenfest model.

Comment: Shouldn't the expected value be $\infty$? Let $p_{jk}(n)$ be the probability to go from $j$ black molecules in box A to $k$ molecules in box A in $n$ steps. In our case $j=500000$ and $k=450000$. So $E = \sum n p_{jk}(n)$. Since $p_{jk}(n)$ does not have to be smaller for larger $n$, the sum tends to infinity. Expressed in other words: Since it is possible to take arbitrary long, the expected value diverges. Nevertheless, this is an interesting question, and knowing $p_{jk}(n)$ would be interesting. However, i found a slightly different formulation of the original problem in the literature.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call $X_t$ the number of white balls in the first urn at time $t$, starting at $X_0 = 0$.

Such a process is called a [Markov Chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain), because $X_t$ takes discrete states and it does not matter how you reached the current state for the future states.

You are looking for the distribution of $T = \min\{t: X_t = 550000\}$. You can do this by declaring that the process stops when $X_t = 550000$, this means that the state $550000$ is declared ["absorbing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Absorbing_states) in the language of Markov processes.

Typically you calculate properties of a markov chain by means of a transition matrix. Some results obtained by this matrix such as expected number of steps, and variance on number of steps are described in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain), however your example has $1000001$ possible states which makes it hard to explicitly write down the $1000001\times 1000001$ matrix.